# Placing list manu items in one bootstrap line with seperators

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problems while building my bootstrap website. 
First of all, i have PSD whichc i have to make as a responsive bootstrap page, but while messing up with an right menu items it seems I've done something wrong. 
[the menu I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p12ST.png)

And this is what i have now:
[menu I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TozWY.png)

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand href="index.html">
             <div class="logo">
                  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Homepage">
             </div>
        </a>
        </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Find undervisning</a>
            <li><a href="#">Om os</a>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </ul>
    <div class="divider">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Support</button></li></br>
            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mail <span class="badge">5</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>


   </div>
```

So, the thing is that:

1. I don't know why, but menu hover does not do the job right. I included this in CSS

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a: hover {
color:#0295d5;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header"> 
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand href="index.html">
     <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Homepage">
     </div>
   </a>
   </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Find undervisning</a>
    <li><a href="#">Om os</a>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
   </ul>
  <div class="divider">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Support</button></li></br>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mail <span class="badge">5</span></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  
   
    </div> 
  </div>
```

2. Take a look at that right side icons, I need to make them seperated with that vertical line
3. And is that Icon with badge possible to make!? (take a look at first header image.

Basically, I need to recreate this menu correctly in bootstrap 3 and make it responsive.

Comment: When using the code snippet, please ensure that you are indeed reproducing the layout as intended—such as including the necessary frameworks. All I see is an unstyled markup.

Comment: Use the class `.navbar-right` on the elements you would like to line up on the right. and http://fontawesome.io/icons/ will have the email icon you need

Comment: Just noticed you have navbar-right in there, but it is in the wrong place.  Needs to be on the div with class divider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of problems in your html, missing `"` after a class name, using `</br>` in a `ul` between two `li`s is not valid, and others.

To see these issues, use a good IDE like phpStorm, or, you can even paste your code into jsFiddle and it'll point out issues. T[his is a jsFiddle with your current code](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/d160vLqm/46/), see all the red? Those will show you where you have issues.

In your css `a: hover` should be `a:hover`

For the pipe between each element use:

```
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: " | ";
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

For the badge, something like this:

```
.mail .badge.danger {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d43f3a;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    top: -4px;
    right: -8px;
}


<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope mail" aria-hidden="true">
     <span class="badge danger">5</span>
</span>
```

### Here are examples putting all of these things together:

#### [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/d160vLqm/48/)

**(You'll need to make the snippet full screen)**

```css
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right{
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
     color:#0295d5;
 }
 .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right .glyphicon{ 
 font-size:24px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right li{
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: " | ";
    margin-right:10px;
}

.mail .badge.danger {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d43f3a;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    top: -4px;
    right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Homepage">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Find undervisning</a>
          <li><a href="#">Om os</a>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </ul>
      <div class="divider">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Support</button>
          </li>
          <li>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope mail" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="badge danger">5</span>
          </span> 
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I place more divider class items? When I try to add for example another icon, it's not aligned properly. Take a look http://i63.tinypic.com/oiu0wp.png

Comment: That depends on what exactly you are trying to add, but adding more shouldnt be an issue, see https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/d160vLqm/50/

Comment: Just make sure you are adding a whole new `li` with the icon stuff inside and not adding another icon to the current `li`

Comment: @EdmundsMārtinsons I see the image in your comment now, can you make a jsFiddle with your html? looks like you need to tweak some css for that dropdown but Ill need to see the html to know where

Comment: @EdmundsMārtinsons lose the rule you have for `.navbar-right{}` in that fiddle. Then update `.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right .mail{}` to `.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right .glyphicon{}` from there, you'll need to tweak the css for each element to suit your needs, see https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/6396t6g7/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand href="index.html">
             <div class="logo">
                  <img src="#" alt="Homepage">
             </div>
        </a>
        </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
        </li>
        <li>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
  Messages <span class="badge">4</span>
</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

I think this code works properly. 



    www.MatrixHosting.in, Affordable Windows Hosting Plans in India starts from Rs 99/month.
```